# I am trying to update the score that has been blitted but it doesnt change

Tags: python, pygame

```
class Score:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Colour = (230, 230, 230)
        self.x = 25
        self.y = 0
        self.Shape = pygame.Rect((self.x, self.y), (200, 100))
        self.Team1Score = 0
        self.Team2Score = 0
        self.Title = f"{self.Team1Score}  -  {self.Team2Score}"
        self.text_type = pygame.font.SysFont('arialunicode', 40).render(self.Title, True, (0, 0, 0))
        self.text_rect = self.text_type.get_rect(center=self.Shape.center)
        self.Score = False

    def DrawScore(self, window):
        pygame.draw.rect(window, self.Colour, self.Shape)
        window.blit(self.text_type, self.text_rect)

    def AddScore(self, score, p1, window):
        self.Score = score
        if p1.Shooting:
            if self.Score:
                if p1.Colour == (255, 0, 0):
                    self.Team1Score += 1
                    self.text_type = pygame.font.SysFont('arialunicode', 40).render(self.Title, True, (0, 0, 0))
                    window.blit(self.text_type, self.text_rect)
                else:
                    self.Team2Score += 1
                    self.text_type = pygame.font.SysFont('arialunicode', 40).render(self.Title, True, (0, 0, 0))
```

I am trying to update the score in my game, however the variable for some reason does not change. How do you update the variable so that the text will be updated on the screen. Do I need to make an update function for the text?

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After changing `Team1Score` or `Team2Score` you have to create again

```
self.Title = f"{self.Team1Score}  -  {self.Team2Score}"
```

to get new string

---

```
if p1.Colour == (255, 0, 0):
    self.Team1Score += 1
else:
    self.Team2Score += 1

self.Title = f"{self.Team1Score}  -  {self.Team2Score}"

self.text_type = pygame.font.SysFont('arialunicode', 40).render(self.Title, True, (0, 0, 0))

#window.blit(self.text_type, self.text_rect)
```